# Template deduction failed on the heap but works on the stack

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a problem with a templated class.
When I instantiate the class on the **stack, it works**.
When I instantiate the same class on the **heap, it fails. (argument deduction)**
I don't understand why...

**Infos:** I'm using gcc 7.2.0 with c++17.

here an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

template <class ReturnType, class ClassName, class... Args>
class MethodPtr
{
public:
    typedef ReturnType (ClassName::*Method)(Args...);

    MethodPtr(ClassName* ptr, Method m) : _p(ptr), _m(m)
    {
        (ptr->*m)(4);
    }

    ClassName* _p;
    Method _m;
};

class Example
{
public:
    Example()
    {
        dotest(this, &Example::func);
    }

    template <class Ptr, class Func>
    void dotest(Ptr ptr, Func func)
    {
        // works
        MethodPtr(ptr, func);

        // don't works
        //std::make_unique<MethodPtr>(ptr, func);
        //new MethodPtr(ptr, func);

        //works
        std::make_unique<decltype(MethodPtr(ptr, func))>(ptr, func);
        new decltype(MethodPtr(ptr, func))(ptr, func);
    }

    void func(int i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Example example;
}
```

Do you have a solution to avoid the decltype?

Thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The fact `new MethodPtr(ptr, func)` fails the deduction is a compiler bug indeed. According to [[dcl.type.class.deduct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.class.deduct#2):

> A placeholder for a deduced class type can also be used in the
>   *type-specifier-seq* in the *new-type-id* or *type-id* of a *new-expression*,
>   or as the *simple-type-specifier* in an explicit type conversion
>   (functional notation) ([expr.type.conv]). A placeholder for a deduced
>   class type shall not appear in any other context.

As you can see, an explicit yes for a new expression, and a blanket ban for anything not explicitly allowed. So `make_unique` *can't* be given a placeholder.

Unless you can migrate to a GCC version where this has been fixed (or you just need to use `make_unique`), you can't avoid `decltype`. Try to introduce a type alias to mitigate the inconvenience.

Answer (score 6):

In latest gcc and clang it works - this `new MethodPtr(ptr, func)`. So for gcc7.2 - it is a bug.

For `unique_ptr(new MethodPtr(ptr, func))` - it cannot work - because in C++  - at this level, having `MethodPtr*` - we cannot distinguish between `unique_ptr<MethodPtr[]>` and `unique_ptr<MethodPtr>` - so it cannot be deduced.

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). Passing simply `MethodPtr` (class template) as a non-template type parameter of function template (`std::make_unique`) was never allowed, and class template argument deduction didn't change that.

`new MethodPtr{ptr, func};` works, by looking at the reference, but I can't say the reason why should that be different to `new MethodPtr(ptr, func);`

Comment: `new MethodPtr(ptr, func)` is correct, it's a gcc bug.